# Convert number of years into dateName?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm calculating the datediff in years and getting a numerical value (Ex: 16.166666) What would be the best solution to turn that value into Date Names.

For example 16.166 years would turn into:  16 years and 1 month?

Comment: In the front end?!

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` function return `INT` how did you get `16.166666` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @Value float= 16.166

Select Years   = floor(@Value)
      ,Months  = floor((@Value - floor(@Value)) * 12)
      ,OrAsStr = ltrim(
                 replace(
                 replace(
                 concat(' ',floor(@Value),' Years ',floor((@Value - floor(@Value)) * 12),' Months')
                 ,' 1 Years ',' 1 Year ')
                 ,' 1 Months',' 1 Month')
                 )
```

**Returns**

```
Years   Months  OrAsStr
16      1       16 Years 1 Month
```

Comment: _I'm calculating the datediff in years.._ confuse me a bit, cause `DATEDIFF()` return `INT`. Good catch ;)

Comment: True, I forgot to add that I multiply by 1.0 to convert to numeric.

Comment: @Swazzy Are you trying to calucate the diff between two `DATE` columns?

Comment: Breaking it out by Integers then concatenating is a great idea! Will definitely be using this . Thanks again @John Cappelletti

Comment: I have two date columns which I need to find the date difference , then convert to a string: Ex: 16 years and 1 month.. make sense? @Sami

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment

> I have two date columns which I need to find the date difference , then convert to a string: Ex: 16 years and 1 month.

You can do like

```
DECLARE
       @Start DATE = '2000-01-01',
       @End   DATE = '2016-02-01';

SELECT CAST(T.Years AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Years and ' + 
       CAST(DATEDIFF(Month, @Start, DATEADD(Year, - T.Years, @End)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Months.'
FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(Year, @Start, @End) Years
    ) T;
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(Year, @Start, @End) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
       ' Years and ' + 
       CAST(
             DATEDIFF(
                      Month, 
                      @Start, 
                      DATEADD(Year, - DATEDIFF(Year, @Start, @End), 
                      @End
                     )
           ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' Months.';
```

Returns

```
+------------------------+
| 16 Years and 1 Months. |
+------------------------+
```